# Formula gives error, using IFNA and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel file with two sheets. One needes to pull information from the other, and if it can't find, it should put 0. Using the following formula but gives error "An issue has been found with this formula" and not sure why:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B27;Sheet2!D1:D999;7;FALSE),"0")
```

In this example H27 should look up the SKU from B27 on Sheet2 with the same SKU in column D and take over its value from column J (which is the 7th column after D). See image.

[image: Image with Sheet1 and Sheet2]

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Try with commas instead of semi colons?

Comment: `Sheet2!D1:D999` is just a single column. Use `D1:J999` if anything. Sidenote: Don't you have `XLOOKUP()`?

Comment: Or rather, consistently with either commas or semicolons, not with both.

Comment: @findwindow Already tried, but Excel says it should be with semi colons.

Comment: Works for me if I use commas.

Comment: @JvdV It should indeed look for the SKU in column D, which is why I put Sheet2!D1:D999

Comment: Then you have misunderstood how `VLOOKUP()` works. I recommend you read about it in the documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: JvdV is saying you need D:J if you want to return that column.

Comment: @findwindow That means your locale uses commas for the [function argument separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formula-errors). Other locales may use something else.

Comment: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B27;Sheet2!D1:J999;7;FALSE);"0")`

Comment: I got it working with `=XLOOKUP(B27;Sheet2!D$1:D$999;Sheet2!J$1:J$999;"0")` suggested by JvdV but also thanks to ScottCraner for the suggestion. I also added $ so the cell numbers where it looks into won't change.